# merge 2 images into one just like instagram

Tags: ios, xcode

I am trying to figure out to get a single image pit of 2 image views like instagram
These are the 2 images. Thanks in advance.

```
 UIImageView *photoImageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(20.0f, 42.0f, 280.0f, 280.0f)];
[photoImageView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor blackColor]];
[photoImageView setImage:self.image];
[photoImageView setContentMode:UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit];

//Add overlay
UIImage *overlayGraphic = [UIImage imageNamed:@"chiu"];
UIImageView *overlayGraphicView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:overlayGraphic];
overlayGraphicView.frame = CGRectMake(30, 100, 260, 200);
[photoImageView addSubview:overlayGraphicView];
```

Comment: What problem are you having? What have you tried so far?

Comment: You've not described a problem.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure you can do this directly with just a `UIImageView` control. I think you're going to have to get into low-level drawing routines to get this done.

**Option 1 (not recommended, just trying to answer the original question):**

Have you tried placing the overlay `UIImageView` on top of the "main" `UIImageView` and setting its opacity to something less than 1 (say 0.4)? It's a crude hack, but it might get you somewhere.

**Option 2 (probably the better path to travel):**

Create an image context and then draw your "base" and "overlay" images on it. Then you'll have a `UIImage` you can output and will only need 1 `UIImageView`. Something like this (NOTE: this is a basic outline; you will need to add a LOT of time to get exactly what you want out of it!):

```
UIImage *baseImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"base"];
UIImage *overlayImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"overlay"];

UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(baseImage.size, NO, 0);

CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();

CGRect rect = CGRectMake(0, 0, baseImage.size.width, baseImage.size.height);

CGContextDrawImage(context, rect, baseImage.CGImage);
CGContextDrawImage(context, rect, overlayImage.CGImage);

UIImage *combined = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();

UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
```